# Where can I view older Mapbox GL JS API documentation?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm building an app with `mapbox-gl@0.44.2` and the latest version of Mapbox GL JS is 0.46.0. The API documentation on their website always reflects the latest release, but I still need to read the docs for this older version. Is it available somewhere on their website, or on their GitHub? 
I've looked around the mapbox GitHub repos but I don't think I'm looking at the right branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's on the Mapbox GL JS GitHub repository:

You can do the following:

1. Go to the `v0.44.2` tree: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/tree/v0.44.2
2. Download ZIP file of the repository (green button named "Clone or download")
3. [Prepare your development enviroment for your OS](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#preparing-your-development-environment).
   You don't need to clone the repostory since you've downloaded it before. Just extract the ZIP file and execute `yarn install` within the `mapbox-gl-js-0.44.2` directory.
4. Run `npm run start-docs` to [start a documentation server locally](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/tree/v0.44.2/docs#running-the-documentation-server-locally).
5. Use the printed URL to view the documentation, in my case it is `http://localhost:8080/mapbox-gl-js/api/`:

[image: Docs_44.2]